# Handling error object in Redux Actions using axios and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, error-handling, axios

actually I made request from redux to my backend using axios, but there is an issue, I successfully got response in try block in **res.data** object but how will I get error which is 400 or 404 or 401 error in catch block.

My code snippet is:

**Backend**

```
try {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Incorect email or password' });
  }

  // Password check
  // Return error if password does not match

  res.send(user);
} catch (err) {
  // Server error
}
```

**Redux Actions**

```
try {
  const res = await axios.post('/users', loginData);

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data
  });
} catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_FAIL,
    payload: err.data.error
  });
}
```

So here my question is where I get 400 or 404 or 401 error object
In **err.data.err**
Or In **err.response.data.err**
Or where ?
There is lot more error like validation error etc to handle but I did not get where to get these error ...

Comment: try error.data.status to get err code